MqttBrowserClient with self-signed certificate
Goal
Send messages via MQTT and web socket connections encrypted with TLS/SSL using a self-signed cert (I already know an official cert would be better).
Server-side
I have a docker container set up to host a Mosquitto broker for both MQTT and Web Socket connections.
Client-side
I have a Dart app that publishes messages via MQTT using MqttServerClient. It doesn't like that I'm using a self-signed cert, but it works fine after setting the 'onBadCertificate' field to return true, circumventing the issue.
I have a Flutter web app which tries to send messages over wss using MqttBrowserClient.
Issue
The Flutter web app is unsuccessful when it tries to connect to the broker via wss. I can use MQTTX or MQTT Explorer to successfully connect to my broker via wss, so I know it can work in Flutter. The web app can connect successfully if I try connecting via ws, and redeploy the broker to not use encryption. But as of now, the encrypted broker says nothing when I try connecting from my web app.
This is the code I'm running:
const scheme = 'wss';
final server = '$scheme://$host';
final randomClientId = '${defaultMqttClientId}_${Random().nextInt(1000000)}';

final client = MqttBrowserClient.withPort(server, randomClientId, port)
..setProtocolV311()
..keepAlivePeriod = 60
..logging(on: true);

final connMessage = MqttConnectMessage().startClean();
client.connectionMessage = connMessage;
client.connect()

This is my output (I've cut out the reconnect attempts for brevity):
MqttClient::connect - Connection timeout period is 5000 milliseconds
MqttClient::connect - keep alive is enabled with a value of 60 seconds
MqttConnectionKeepAlive:: Initialised with a keep alive value of 60 seconds
MqttConnectionKeepAlive:: Disconnect on no ping response is disabled
MqttConnectionHandlerBase::connect - server wss://127.0.0.1, port 9001
SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect entered
SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 0, auto reconnect in progress false
SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - entered
MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect -  WS URL is wss://127.0.0.1:9001
MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - connection is waiting
MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - websocket has erred
SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 0
Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQTT, ProtocolVersion=4, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=false, WillQos=MqttQos.atMostOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=false, UserNameFlag=false, KeepAlive=60
MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : swcfl_343410


SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
ynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect failed
Network Loggy - MqttService - Connect exception: mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed connection attempts ({3}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message (Missing Connection Acknowledgement?
Network Loggy - MqttService - disconnected

This is the content of my mosquitto.conf:
listener 8883
protocol mqtt
certfile /certs/broker/broker.crt
keyfile /certs/broker/broker.key
allow_anonymous true

listener 9001
protocol websockets
certfile /certs/broker/broker.crt
keyfile /certs/broker/broker.key
allow_anonymous true

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Does this answer your question? Error when trying to connect custom mqtt broker with react and typescript. Basically you cannot load a CA cert via Javascript in a browser (browsers do not permit this for security reasons).

As @Brits said, the only way to make this work with the private CA cert is to pre-load it manually into EVERY browser that will connect. The correct answer it to user a public CA certificate e.g. from LetsEncrypt.
